# Best practice to add time partitions to a table

Tags: hive, emr, hiveql

having an event tables, partitioned by time (year,month,day,hour)
Wanna join a few events in hive script that gets the year,month,day,hour as variables,
how can you add for example also events from all 6 hours prior to my time
without 'recover all...'

10x

Answer (score 0):

So basically what i needed was a way to use a date that the Hive script receives as parameter
and add all partitions 3 hour before and 3 hours after that date, without recovering all partitions and add the specific hours in every Where clause.

Didn't find a  way to do it inside the hive script, so i wrote a quick python code that gets a date and table name, along with how many hours to add from before/after.
When trying to run it inside the Hive script with:
!python script.py tablename ${hivecond:my.date} 3
i was surprised that the variable substition does not take place in a line that starts with !

my workaround was to get the date that the hive script recieved from the log file in the machine using something like:
'cat /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/`ls /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/ |sort -r|head -n 1`/stdout'
and from there you can parse each hive parameter in the python code without passing it via Hive.